# Why 2 variables (int) of the same value has the same memory id (are the same object)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, memory-management

Why `c` and `d` have the same memory id?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.n = number

a = A(1)
b = A(1)
id(a) == id(b)    # False

L1 = [1, 2, 3]
L2 = [1, 2, 3]
id(L1) == id(L2)  # False
```

but

```
c = 1
d = 1
id(c) == id(d)    # True
```

Comment: enjoy coding in python and never use `id` again.

Comment: Can us `c is d` and still will be the same result `True`, even more, giving them value outside the array [-5, 256] it still gives `True`, why? Enjoy unswering me this question.

Comment: that's because your python implementation caches integers outside this range. That's really an implementation detail since integers are immutable anyway. Stop bothering with that, it's not worth it. `id` is for debugging, and to be honest I have never used it.